# Create df columns based on an existing df column that contains delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

One of the columns of my pandas `df` looks like this. It is a long string with `-` as a delimeter. This long string contains some characteristics of a particular product.

`Water Resistant: 10 ATM - Diameter: 48 mm - Sex: Man - Material: RVS IP Gun - Movement: Quartz - Functionality: Alleen Tijd - Glass: Mineraal`

I would like to create columns in that same `df` for each of the object characteristics: Water resistant, Diameter, Sex, etc.

The final result should look something like:

```
Water resistance    Diameter    Sex    Material    Movement
10 ATM              48 mm       Man    RVS IP Gun  Quartz
```

There are also some products for which there is no description. In that case the `df` should look like:

```
Water resistance    Diameter    Sex    Material    Movement
10 ATM              48 mm       Man    RVS IP Gun  Quartz
-                   47 mm       Woman  -           Quartz
10 ATM              -           Woman  UIS         -
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and `pd.DataFrame.from_records`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "Water Resistant: 10 ATM - Diameter: 48 mm - Sex: Man - Material: RVS IP Gun - Movement: Quartz - Functionality: Alleen Tijd - Glass: Mineraal"

ptrn = re.compile(r"([\w\s]+):\s*([\w\s]+)")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict(ptrn.findall(s))])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Water Resistant  Diameter   Sex     Material  Movement  Functionality     Glass
0         10 ATM     48 mm   Man   RVS IP Gun    Quartz    Alleen Tijd   Mineraal
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you have this dataframe:

```
                                                col1
0  Water Resistant: 10 ATM - Diameter: 48 mm - Se...
1  Diameter: 47 mm - Sex: Woman - Movement: Quart...
2  Water Resistant: 13 ATM - Sex: Woman - Materia...
```

Then:

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    df["col1"]
    .apply(
        lambda x: {
            line.split(":")[0]: line.split(":")[1].strip()
            for line in x.split(" - ")
        }
    )
    .tolist()
).fillna("-")
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Water Resistant Diameter    Sex    Material Movement Functionality     Glass
0          10 ATM    48 mm    Man  RVS IP Gun   Quartz   Alleen Tijd  Mineraal
1               -    47 mm  Woman           -   Quartz   Alleen Tijd  Mineraal
2          13 ATM        -  Woman         UIS        -   Alleen Tijd  Mineraal
```

---

EDIT: To handle `NaN` and edge cases:

```py
def fn(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return {}

    out = {}
    for line in x.split(" - "):
        if ":" in line:
            k, v = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
            out[k] = v
    return out


df_out = pd.DataFrame(df["col1"].apply(fn).tolist()).fillna("-")
print(df_out)
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I'm getting the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Liz Are some values without `:` ?

Comment: No... No values without `:`

Comment: I do have some `nan` values tho... It may be that?

Comment: I keep getting an error... :/  I've uploaded the .csv in this gist: https://gist.github.com/glosophy/2aa5238079d261bdc017b1249ed6414c

The column I need to modify is 'attributes'